# Quotes face the wrong way with xepersian and csquotes

Tags: csquotes, xepersian

When I try to use `csquotes` along with `xepersian`, the quotation marks come out facing the wrong way (for right-to-left text).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
"این فقط یک آزمایش است"
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you're going to write in Persian, please remember that the correct quotation mark in Persian is `«...»`. :)

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more general solution, but I was able to solve this with a custom quotation style—just by reversing the left and right quotation marks.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{farsi}
    {\textquotedblright}{\textquotedblleft}
    {\textquotedblleft}{\textquotedblleft}
\setquotestyle{farsi}
\begin{document}
"این فقط یک آزمایش است"
\end{document}
```